# Apply a function separately to each row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I wrote a small function to generate a random string of a fixed length. I want to apply it to a data frame a create a new column where each row for this column has a new string of this fixed length:

```
import random, string

def random_string(length):
    letters = string.printable
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(length))

df['random_string'] = random_string(40)
```

However, applying it this way results in one random string that gets generated for the entire column. Any help on how to apply the function where each row would have a newly generated string would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
df['random_string'] = [random_string(40) for _ in range(df.shape[0])]
```

You need to create a list of random strings instead of setting a column to a scalar value of a single random string.  Your code is essentially doing `df['colname'] = 'A'`.

Another way:

```
df['random_string'] = df.apply(lambda x: random_string(40), axis=1)
```